# Can Spring urls with no mapping be redirected to some default login url?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm using Spring 3 and I tried to access url that has no mapping and I get following warning. Is it possible to redirect urls with no mappings for example to login page?

```
2011-08-16 15:52:25,263 [http-8080-1] WARN  org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/urlwithnomapping] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Section [15.4 Handler mappings](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping) of the Spring 3 reference mentions a *defaultHandler* property.  I believe this is what you want.

Comment: And I found this link also very helpful http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?103544-Spring-3-mvc-default-mapping-handler-to-get-all-unmapped-requests .